# Outputting data from a django app

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

This is probably something really simple but for some reason I just can't seem to do it.

I'm trying to output some data from a blog (app) that I have created. The blog is working fine and out putting the content in the model fields that I have created and outputting to the templates I have specified.

But when tryingn to output the information out to the homepage nothing is showing. I'm fairly new to django and I think I might be missing something.

Do I need to include something to pages that are outside of the app? or do I need to set up somethin in the urls file?

I hope this makes sense as I don't think it's anything to complicated but I just think I'm missing something!

Thanks.

CODE:

```
url(r'blog/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'blog.views.blog', name="blog"),
   url(r'blog/', 'blog.views.blog_index', name="blog_index"),


def blog_index(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.filter(active=True)

    return render_to_response('blog/index.html', {
        'blogs':blogs,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def blog(request, slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, active=True, slug=slug)

    return render_to_response('blog/blog_post.html', {
        'blog': blog
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))





class Blog(TimeStampedActivate):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Can be anything up to 255 character")
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="Give a short description of the news post")
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="This is the main content for the news post")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="blog")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('blog', (), {
            'slug': self.slug
        })
```

Comment: This is lacking too much info. Is your homepage another template? If you are able to get one template showing data from your views why cant you get another one doing the same? We will most likely need to see some examples of what you have set up so far (short examples). Yes it has something to do with urls.py as that is where you define your routes.

Comment: I've added some code for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: All of this looks fine. You have a url entry that properly maps the blog/ to the index view. The only reason you wouldn't be seeing anything is if you didn't set up your blog/index.html template to show it. What does it do?

Comment: Sorry I may have missed something. It's showing fine on the blog index file as the blog index file is the /blog/ landing page. However I wish to pull information through from the blog to the sites homepage.

Comment: This is so vague, I'm sorry. Is your "home" page the domain root "/" and is it being served through django? If so, yes you need a url entry for it and to point it at either the same blog view or another view

Comment: jdi - Apologies for being vague. I have my sites homepage. e.g. mysite.com then my blog app atm is pointing to mysite.com/blog/

However I wish to pull data from the mysite.com/blog/ page where i've created the post and to display some of the information on the homepage. So by looking at what you've said i need to create a new URL and point it to the view i've created. In that case, what would i have to put in the URl as i'm not 100% sure how the URls work.

Comment: Theses are the URL's i currently have linking to the blog - 
url(r'blog/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'blog.views.blog', name="blog"),
   url(r'blog/', 'blog.views.blog_index', name="blog_index"),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that going to `mysite.com/blog/` is displaying correctly, but you also want it to be the sites index page at `mysite.com`?

If so, you need to add a new pattern to your projects `urls.py` file, like so:

`url(r'^$', 'blog.views.blog_index')`

Doing this will make `mysite.com/blog/` and `mysite.com` route to the same view.

Comment: Curiously though, the OP never mentions there being an error when going to the root of the domain. It would seem *something* is routed there otherwise he would see a 404

Comment: Thanks for your replies...I would like the homepage to display the last 4 blog posts. So for example mysite.com/blogs/ would be where all the posts are displayed but on the homepaage i just want the last 4 posts to show. However filtering them is irrelivant at the moment.

Comment: to show only 4 posts you can slice the queryset, `Blog.objects.filter(active=True)[:4]` using another view or `{{blogs|slice:":4" }}` in template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply however the problem i'm having is i can't get anything to output to my homepage. Do i need to create another view for the information to output to the homepage?

Comment: @JoshDavies: Even with your recent clarifications, it still sounds like what you want is what this answer suggests. This is showing you how to map the blog index to a second URL (your domain root "/"). This would be a 3rd url entry. If this is not what you want, then you need to completely redo your question to clearly illustrate.

Comment: Yes this is what I would like, however I can't seem to get it to do. What would I need to put in my URl? Thanks for being patient with me! :)

Comment: @JoshDavies: That url example is what you would put in your `urls.py`. It maps '/' to the blog index just like 'blog/'

Comment: JDI, I'm sorry what I need to do it create a view in the main views.py file and and point the URl to that view, however i'm now having problems linking that view to the URL. 

I keep getting this error message back - blogpost() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: I've posted a more update post with a a little more detail! Sorry for being vague and thanks for your help through all this!

Comment: Here is the update - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091330/no-blog-matches-the-given-query