# Exception Value: blog() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I've been struggling with setting up views / urls in Django for a couple of days. Struggling to get my head around it everyone seems to do it slightly differently.

What i want to achieve is:

I want to have a blog where i can post news posts on the site that will be located at example - mysite.com/blog/ then you can click through to view the posts individually it pulls the slug through from each post. (which pretty much works).

However I want to pull the posts from the blog app so the homepage. So you can view a snippet of the latest posts. I now understand that I need to create a view and a URL outside of the app folder and in the main directory. However i'm struggling to get them to link together. I am currently getting the error message displayed above. 'No Blog matches the given query.' Here is my code for the URL's, Models and the 2 different view folders.

```
//URLS for app and main directory

import authority
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url, include, patterns
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
authority.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    (r'^authority/', include('authority.urls')),
    (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^$', 'views.blog', name='index'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'blog.views.blog', name="blog"),
    url(r'^blog/$', 'blog.views.blog_index', name="blog_index"),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        # Trick for Django to support static files (security hole: only for Dev environement! remove this on Prod!!!)
        url(r'^admin/pages/page(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.PAGES_MEDIA_ROOT}),
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        url(r'^admin_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )

urlpatterns += patterns('',      
    (r'^', include('pages.urls')),
    )
```

//MAIN VIEW FOR HOMEPAGE

```
  from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
    from django.template import RequestContext

from blog.models import Blog, NewsPost

def blog_index(request):
blogs = Blog.objects.filter(active=True)

return render_to_response('index.html', {
    'blogs':blogs,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

//VIEWS FOR BLOG APP

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext

from blog.models import Blog, NewsPost

def blog_index(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.filter(active=True)

    return render_to_response('blog/index.html', {
        'blogs':blogs,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def blog(request, slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, active=True, slug=slug)

    return render_to_response('blog/blog_post.html', {
        'blog': blog
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

//MODELS FROM THE BLOG APP

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



 class TimeStampedActivate(models.Model):
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Controls 
        whether or now this news post is live")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Blog(TimeStampedActivate):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Can be 
    anything up to 255 character")
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="Give a short 
    description of the news post")
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="This is the main 
    content for the news post")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="blog")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('blog', (), {
            'slug': self.slug
        })

class NewsPost(TimeStampedActivate):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="title of the post")
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="Give a short 
    description of the news post")
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="This is the main 
    content for the news post")
    publish_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(),
    help_text="Choose when the post is visible")

    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, related_name="posts")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish_at', '-modified', '-created']
```

If you need anymore information feel free to ask! I'm new to all this so go easy! :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like your `blogpost` view should just be the same as your `blog_index` one, surely? You seem to want more or less the same thing - a list of blog posts. What's the difference?

Comment: Hi Daniel - Ok so i've copied and pasted and the view from the blog app changed the name of the model that the URL imports. I'm not getting this error message - cannot import name blog

Comment: Sorry, what? "changed the name of the model that the URL imports" - what does this mean? If you've changed some code, please update the post above, and show the actual error message.

Comment: This is the line where i'm getting the error - from views import blog on the URL's page.. I don't see what's wrong with it? Does it conflict that i have another view called blog in another views.py file?

Comment: Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

blog() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: The error message is displayed in the comment above. I was getting the import error because i was importing blog and not blog_index... However i'm getting the error above.

Comment: Please show your full/actual URLS for app and main directory. Not just the snippet.

Comment: Updated the URL's page for you. I have also updated the error message in the title. - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
url(r'$', blog),
```

To

```
url(r'$', 'views.blog_index', name='index'),
```

Or write a separate view.

The reason you're getting your error, is because you're attempting to execute the `blog` function which expects a `slug` from your title page. What you're wanting to do is show the `index` from your title page which does not take a `slug`.

Also, the following is going to cause you pain:

```
from blog.views import blog_index, blog
from views import blog_index
```

Which `blog_index` do you want to be using? You're better off using `'views.blog_index'` notation in your URLs. Delete those imports above, and only use string based view names in your URLs like you've done for `blog/` and `blog_index/`.

Edit: this is what your entire URLs should show (to get this working..)

```
import authority
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url, include, patterns
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
authority.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    (r'^authority/', include('authority.urls')),
    (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^$', 'views.blog', name='index'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'blog.views.blog', name="blog"),
    url(r'^blog/$', 'blog.views.blog_index', name="blog_index"),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        # Trick for Django to support static files (security hole: only for Dev environement! remove this on Prod!!!)
        url(r'^admin/pages/page(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.PAGES_MEDIA_ROOT}),
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        url(r'^admin_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )

urlpatterns += patterns('',      
    (r'^', include('pages.urls')),
    )
```

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks for your reply really appreciate it. I've now got something to load. If I move the url(r'/$', blog_index), URL to the bottom of the 2 blog URL's the /blog/ pages load fine. However I have add the / in the URL. The problem I have then is the homepage is loading just HTML with no styles etc

Comment: Update to the post above:

If I go to the any page with a trailing slash other than /blog/ it loads the template with the index.html (like i want it) however when I go to the homepage without the / e.g mysite.com it loads the first page in the pages CMS

Comment: @JoshDavies I've updated my answer by modifying the URLs to add `^` `/` and `$`. Make the above changes and let me know  how you go.

Comment: @JoshDavies also note that django expects there to be a trailing slash `/` for all of its URLs. There is a django setting called something like APPEND_TRAILING_SLASH that you might want to look in to.

Comment: Ok, I've now changed the urls.py file to look like the one you have edited however i'm now getting this error message:

Exception Type:  ImportError
Exception Value:  No module named views

Comment: You probably need to supply the fully qualified path rather than a relative import path as in `project.views.blog` where project is the folder name that your `views.py` file lives (that folder must be on your python path).